I have WSL disabled in Windows Features, and I've uninstalled all WSL related software. But getting a WSL related error in the Event Viewer
I'm getting the following error (Event ID: 7023) in Event Viewer:
The WSLService service terminated with the following error: 
The service cannot be started, either because it is disabled or because no enabled devices are associated with it.

WSL is not installed:

Looking at Autoruns under the services tab, I see this:

WslInstaller
Windows Subsystem for Linux: Windows Subsystem for Linux lets developers run a GNU/Linux environment -- including most command-line tools, utilities, and applications -- directly on Windows, unmodified, without the overhead of a traditional virtual machine or dualboot setup. (Verified) 

Microsoft Corporation
C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\MicrosoftCorporationII.WindowsSubsystemForLinux_2.2.4.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\wslinstaller.exe    
Tue Aug 13 22:41:54 2024

WSLService
WSL Service: 
WSL Service (Verified) Microsoft Corporation
C:\Program Files\WSL\wslservice.exe
Thu Apr 25 18:19:24 2024    


How can I prevent this event log error?
Should I ignore it?
Is WSL completely disabled, or did I mess something up?
Do I need to perform additional steps to disable it?
Should I delete or disable the WSL related services?

Running wsl -v in a command prompt gives me the following:
WSL version: 2.2.4.0
Kernel version: 5.15.153.1-2
WSLg version: 1.0.61
MSRDC version: 1.2.5326
Direct3D version: 1.611.1-81528511
DXCore version: 10.0.26091.1-240325-1447.ge-release
Windows version: 10.0.19045.4780

So, it does appear that WSL is installed somehow.
I looked at Settings > Apps > Apps & Features, and WSL isn't listed anywhere in that dialog. So, I'm still searching for a way to completely uninstall.

Did you uninstall WSL? WSL hasn’t been installed from the Windows Feature GUI for more than 2 years. Based on the events being logged you most definitely have WSL still installed. What is the output of wsl -l -v?

wsl -v gives me: WSL version: 2.2.4.0 Kernel version: 5.15.153.1-2 WSLg version: 1.0.61 MSRDC version: 1.2.5326 Direct3D version: 1.611.1-81528511 DXCore version: 10.0.26091.1-240325-1447.ge-release Windows version: 10.0.19045.4780
So it does look like it's still installed. What do I do to uninstall it?

Instead of unformatted comment [edit] your question. You can uninstall it from Settings > Apps > Apps & Features

Edited my post. I tried uninstalling from Settings > Apps > Apps & Features, but it's not listed anywhere in that list. Any other ideas?

I just ran wsl --uninstall in an admin command prompt. Going to restart now and see if that fixed things.

That fixed it. Services are gone after a reboot. Will add an answer.

It appears WSL2 was still installed somehow after uninstalling with Settings > Apps > Apps & Features. Running wsl --uninstall in an admin cmd/Powershell prompt and then rebooting fixed it. The WSL services are now gone.
